# Use simple functions instead of decorators in class-validator

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I am using [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) from `TypeStack` to ensure my class members are properly validated when setting. The code looks like this:

```
class Foo {
@isEmail
email: string;
}
```

Since the project is called **class**-validator, I am still wondering if I can use this decorators as simple functions that return a boolean value.

Comment: I think I just found what I needed. The functions are lower-case, so instead of `IsEmail` as advertised, the internal functions are simply called `isEmail`